# File permissions with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, chmod

I have a VPS that i run and I want to change my file permissions, but I don't think I'm doing it right. I originally chmod'd my files to 777, which from what I hear isn't exactly practical for security purposes. My initial reason behind this was that I have a directory (example.com/dir/) that has two project folders 'a' and 'b'. When I go access '/dir' it shows those two folders. I want to be able to redirect '/dir' while '/dir/a' and '/dir/b' is still accessible like a normal page. On top all of this I want to remain to edit my files via ftp without having all my permissions set to 777.

Is there a simple method to go about this? I know it's a lot to ask, but this aspect of server security has always puzzled me.

Answer (score 0):

Chmod usually takes 3 octal digit as input, They are actually sums of digits, wherein each digit represents a certain permission.

Have a look at this

http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/